# RegEx for JAVA using "AND"

Tags: java, regex, string, match

I have this string value:

```
String value = Country, Location, Sample
```

I tried

```
value.matches("/(?=.*Country.*)(?=.*Location.*)/")
```

But it return to false.
Can someone help me to find and get the result to true? the condition is 
Location and Country must both in one string, in regex way.
Thanks!

Comment: Then you should remove `/` and replace it with `"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to modify your pattern a bit and remove the `/` delimiters:

```
value.matches("(?=.*Country)(?=.*Location).*")
```

Comment: how about not getting the commas(,). Can you solve that for me? :) pls @hwnd

Comment: What do you mean not getting the commas?